# Designing a Torsional Rotary Flexure - Finite Element Freeware?

Tags: finite-element-method, flexures

I am interested in designing and building a flexure based telescope tracking accessory.  The core of the design would be what I think is called a "rotary flexure" or "Twist-it" or torsional rotary hinge...?  Picture two metal disks, say something like two hockey pucks.  They are spaced say one inch apart.  Connecting the two pucks are what I have seen referred to as "reeds" or "beams"...four of them at ninety degree spacing.  The reeds would be something like spring steel.  This rotary flexure would allow rotation for small angles around the axis of the pucks.  So looking down on this mechanism would look like an "O" with an "X" inside.

The question:  looks like some kind of finite element software could allow me to model this to help determine parameters such as reed thickness, width and length.  I can't afford a commercial license (just a hobbyist).  Is there a freeware "tool chain" that would allow me to capture the design and model the stresses and strains?  I am willing to climb a steep learning curve if I knew there was something viable at the top.  TIA.

Comment: Why?? https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&sxsrf=AB5stBgzdmakTNx2IK5nHzqpapvn8eK9qw:1690930997398&q=telescope+off-axis+guider+design&tbm=shop&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjomMHryLyAAxX8k2oFHW70DgoQ0pQJegQIDBAB&biw=1366&bih=619&dpr=1#spd=17434182521122889513

Comment: A hand calculation* will be just as, or more, accurate than FEA by an inexperienced user. However, Calculix is free and good. * Ah I'm guessing the reeds are only restrained along part of their length. A handcalc could provide a lower bound for stiffness.